# Multiple commands inside a docker container bash script

Tags: bash, docker

I want to excute some commands inside a container but the second one doesn't want to be executed inside the container so `grep` can't find the file in home directory of my container. Does someone has the same problem?

```
# Throughput
    docker exec -i container_client bash << EOF >> mystatistics.xls
    (sockperf throughput --tcp --msg-size=256 -i $ipaddcontainer -p 12345 -t 10)> my_output_file_troughput.txt
    echo "Bridge mode" "," `grep 'BandWidth is ' my_output_file_troughput.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 5`
    exit
    EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use here-docs, you should remember about the difference when quoting or not quoting the `EOF` token. Without qoutes, any command substitution will be executed in the main shell, not in Docker. Compare these two:

```
$ cat <<EOF
$(echo ok)
EOF

ok
```

And:

```
$ cat <<"EOF"
$(echo ok)
EOF

$(echo ok)
```

So if you want to pass commands including command substitution to Docker, you should quote the token.

By the way,

1. Why are you using a subshell for `sockperf` btw?
2. The ticks are obsolete and the new syntax is `$()`.